# CAtlNavigateData can not deal with special symbol such as +

Tags: c++, special-characters, atl

```
CAtlNavigateData navData;
CStringA m_strForm = "name=+++&priv=1&password="；
navData.SetSocketTimeout(m_nMilliSecond);
navData.SetMethod(ATL_HTTP_METHOD_POST); 
navData.SetPostData((BYTE*)(LPSTR)(LPCSTR)m_strForm, m_strForm.GetLength(), QHTTP_FORM_URLENCODE);
```

I catch the posted package, and find post data 
`name = ""`, it should be  `name="+++"`. Does `SetPostData(...)` can not deal with special symbol. How can I avoid this?

Thanks for Snazzer's answer. Does ATL provides API for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode your string, so replace the '+' with '%2B'

```
CStringA m_strForm = "name=%2B%2B%2B&priv=1&password="；
```

For more information, check out [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encoding)

Comment: Is there any URL encoding APIs?
Need I write it myself? Many thanks!

Comment: AtlEscapeUrl ? (http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=AtlEscapeUrl&esrch=FT1)